# How to do Empirical Bayes Estimation of HLM parameteres in R?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I am modelling the impacts on students' achievemens using HLM (2 levels only), with the lme4 package in R. I would like now to estimate the Empirical Bayes Estimates and the Empirical Bayes Grand Means for each group of the 2nd level, using R.

Please, would you be able to point me to any source or give me any tips on that?

Much apreciated.

Comment: Have you found come across [this source](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Regression-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Models/dp/052168689X)? The authors present a number of examples using R to call in BUGS for multilevel analyses. It may have what you need.